# Python selenium web-driver: selecting value from the dropdown list (No such Element Exception)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract the user reviews from google app using selenium webdriver. I loaded all reviews on the web-browser. Now I want to change the 'Most relevant' option of review page to 'Newest' option as shown in the picture.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
baseurl = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapmyrun.android2&showAllReviews=true'
driver.get(baseurl)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='OA0qNb ncFHed']//div[@class='MocG8c UFSXYb LMgvRb KKjvXb']//span[@class='vRMGwf oJeWuf']").click()
```

When I ran the code, it throws following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='OA0qNb ncFHed']//div[@class='MocG8c UFSXYb LMgvRb KKjvXb']//span[@class='vRMGwf oJeWuf']"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on `google review options` as `Newest` Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath` option.

```
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapmyrun.android2&showAllReviews=true")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[./span[text()='Most relevant']]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@role='option'][./span[text()='Newest']]"))).click()
```

---

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply click the div and click newest. Your class is dynamic and will change it's better to get an indentification that won't change.

```
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapmyrun.android2&showAllReviews=true")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Most relevant']/parent::div").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='Newest']")[1].click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I ran the code, it thorws an error on the last line. The error is IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Add more time or start using webdriver waits.